# How do i adept different sized floating divs to stay side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have different sized divs  set to float:left and long divs are pushing the bottom rows down and creating blank area .How do i remove the blank areas or adjust them to stay side by side. I am using bootstrap framework. Thank you for your help. here is my link. http://kazi.pixub.com/abide/

```
 div structure:                      

<div class="article">

                    <span class="category">Ministry</span>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2 class="article-title">The Church's Not-So-Good Future:</h2>
                        <p class="author"> by Author U. Love</p>
                        <p class="details">
                            Seriously, what is the future of the church? I could go a hundred different ways with this thought;
                            marriage, globalization, fossil fulels, consumerism, theology..</p>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <img class="article-image" src="images/article-image.jpg">
                </div>


    css:

.article {
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: if you mean something like Pinterest, then you can use Masonry library

Comment: I have added Masonry, now the whole area moved to right side over sidebar.

Comment: and did you read the documentation?

Comment: I have added script to init masonry , maybe cant get it work

Comment: Fixed it following www.maurizioconventi.com/2012/06/19/responsive-example-integrating-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-masonry/  Thank you Morvy!